# “Limited Connectivity” error after attempting to connect to a wireless access point on fresh install of KDE Neon ( based on Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, iwlwifi, access-point, kde-neon

Everything works fine when I connect to the main router, once I connect to a wireless access point (different SSID and does not have a DHCP server) I'm not able to connect to the internet with a **"Limited Connectivity"** error showing up.

Keep in mind that the access point I've setup over Ethernet has always worked for all of the devices connected to it, even other Linux distributions, so is it safe to assume that the issue is most definitely in my distribution installation or maybe network drivers?

System information:

```
Main router IP:  192.168.0.1
Access Point IP: 192.168.0.254

Operating System:   KDE neon 5.22
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.3 KDE
Frameworks Version: 5.84.0
Qt Version:         5.15.3 
Kernel Version:     5.8.0-63-generic (64-bit) 
Graphics Platform:  X11
Processors:         4 × Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory:             19.0 GiB of RAM Graphics
Processor:          Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520
Network description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi
driverversion=5.8.0-63-generic
firmware=36.77d01142.0 8000C-36.ucode
latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:131 memory:df100000-df101fff
```

Comment: Maybe check logs on your clients for dhcp errors and post what you find.  Normally since you're on the same segment there they should be passed through but something could be misconfigured.  Also it would help if you post what wifi tech your AP is using and what your client adapter is.